# Change specific character of a text in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a 625 digit long number to store in MySQL containing only 0 1 and 2 digits. The best way I've found to store it so far is as VARCHAR(625). I suspect that there are better ways to do it, I'm just not sure how.

I want to run a query such as "change the 128th character of the text to 1"  without having to query the text into PHP, change it from there, and write the new text into the DB.

So the question is: what's the simplest method of doing this, and what field type is optimal for this kind of stuff?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813712/changing-a-specific-char-in-a-mysql-string. You'll find your answer there.

Comment: not exactly, but yea pretty much... I did look around, but didn't find anything. thanks tho

Comment: How is that not what you want? Please expand on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user INSERT() String function

give it a try

```
UPDATE tbl set field = INSERT(field,128,1,'1') where id = primary key
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be doing things like "change the 128th character of the text to 1" then I'd recommend keeping the data type as VARCHAR(625). If the length will *always* be 625 then you could use CHAR.

This will change the 128th character to 1 in MySQL:

```
UPDATE your_table set your_column =
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING(your_column, 1, 127), '1', SUBSTRING(your_column, 129))
```

Comment: Just as well - with CHAR you end up with trailing spaces if the value isn't *exactly* as long as the column, and sooner or later that spells trouble. BTW you're correct to choose the answer from @new_developer as the "best answer" - I overlooked `INSERT` and this is exactly the situation it was made for :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only storing numbers, why not use int(625) instead of varchar?

You can use a replace command, but you'll have to know what to replace with

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’);
```

If you don't know what exactly you're replace with, you can replace the "replace found string with this string" with a sub query. Using length and substr to split, replace what you want, and concat back together.

This example should make what I'm saying make more sense
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbc21/2/0quey

Comment: try it in sqlfiddle and let us know

Comment: Display width 625 in int(625) can be max 255. Also integer display width is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

A complex alternative:

Replacing 5th character to 'r' where primary key is 30:

```
update `myTable` set `myField`= regexp_replace(`myField`, '.', 'r', 5, 1) where `id`=30 limit 1
```